# How do you generate a list of descending magnitude in R?

Tags: r

I have a list in R that looks like this

```
[1] 1067  576    0    0    0  786    0
```

What I want is another list that is ordered in such a way as to tell the order of elements from largest to smallest, so in this case it would report

```
1 6 2
```

That is, the 1st element is the largest, then the 6th element, then the 2nd element.

Thoughts?

Comment: calling your vector `v`, `rev(order(v))` returns: `1 6 2 7 5 4 3`

Comment: `order(x,decreasing=TRUE)` specifically.

Comment: or in the same fashion `order(-v)`

Comment: `z <- order(x,decreasing=TRUE); z[!(z %in% which(x == 0)) ]`

Comment: It's difficult to believe that you did any searching.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to want to exclude the 0's.

```
v <- c(1067,  576,    0,    0,    0,  786,    0)
rev(order(v))[1:length(v[v>0])]
# [1] 1 6 2
```

You could also use:

```
order(v, decreasing=TRUE)[1:length(v[v>0])]
```

which amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of variations on a theme:

```
freq <- c(1067,576,0,0,0,786,0)
```

Jeremy (ish)

```
order(-freq)[order(-freq) %in% which(freq != 0)]
```

Richard

```
order(-freq)[seq_along(freq[freq != 0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
order(-v)[1:sum(!!v)]
[1] 1 6 2
```